# Laravel Backpack "Cannot find 'relationship' field view in any of the regular locations"

Tags: laravel-backpack

I bought backpack pro, in my local development environment it works, but online I get this error:
"Cannot find 'relationship' field view in any of the regular locations"
I published all vendor via FTP.
Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you’re using the “realtionship” field type but do not have the PRO addon installed, that actually provides that field.

You can see a breakdown of the free vs paid features here: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/features-free-vs-paid

To fix this, you can either:

A) purchase and install Backpack PRO;

B) replace the “relationship” field with a FREE alternative like “select” or “select_multiple” if they support your type of Eloquent relationship;

Comment: I have the same problem. I have purchased a license for the PRO version of Backpack. In my local environment, it works perfectly when developing, but when I upload the vendor folder to the production server via FTP, even though I can see the contents of the "backpack/pro/resources/views" folder, it throws the error "Cannot find 'slug' field view in any of the regular locations."

Answer (score 0):

I think he bougth the PRO, as stated in his first sentence.

Make sure you have your licence key set in your `Production Environment` .env file.

Can you check your `vendor/backpack` folder and see what packages are inside? If `pro` is there, can you see the contents ?

Since you told you used ftp to upload your files is possible that you don't have access to composer ? If you do, what's the output of `composer why backpack/pro` ?

Cheers

Comment: I have the same problem. I have purchased a license for the PRO version of Backpack. In my local environment, it works perfectly when developing, but when I upload the vendor folder to the production server via FTP, even though I can see the contents of the "backpack/pro/resources/views" folder, it throws the error "Cannot find 'slug' field view in any of the regular locations."